# How to divide each element of column by this column module efficient way?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large `np.array`

```
[1.,    2.,    3.,    ...]
[1000., 1001., 1002., ...]
[2000., 2001., 3002., ...]
[3000., 3001., 3002., ...]
```

for example. And I want to divide each element from each column by the module of this column.
This is an example for the first column:

col_1 = {1, 1000, 2000, 3000}

module_col_1 = [image]

new_col_1 = {1/module, 1000/module, 2000/module, 3000/module}

Using `for` loops is too slow. How could I do this calculations without `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
M = np.array([[1,2,3],[1000,1001,2002],[2000,2001,2002]])
M / np.sqrt(np.sum(M**2,axis=0))
array([[4.47213551e-04, 8.93890482e-04, 1.05959998e-03],
       [4.47213551e-01, 4.47392186e-01, 7.07106384e-01],
       [8.94427102e-01, 8.94337427e-01, 7.07106384e-01]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
modules = np.sqrt(np.sum(arr * arr, axis=0))
new_arr = arr / modules
```